# AnimatedDiff running on ComfyUI outputting black squares

Tags: python-3.x

Running on a Mac Studio with Apple M2 Ultra chip. The ComfyUI produces still images just fine. But when I run AnimateDiff I get black square frames and MP4's. I am running Python 3.7.9 as this is the version of Python that works with ComfyUI

I tried launching the ComfyUI server with --lowvram and --no vram and got the same results. I set the pixel dimensions to 512x512. I understand the Mac Studio doesn't actually have vram, the ram is unified. It has 64 GB of 'unified memory'.